# Tensorflow installation on JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

If I download Tensorflow package for windows x64 externally without using pip installer on JUPYTER NOTEBOOK,
then HOW should I install it on JUPYTER NOTEBOOK ????

Please help..

Comment: It is far easy to pip install tensorflow. You don't have to specifically install tensorflow on jupyter notebook. You just have to import on jupyter notebook.`pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

if it lies in your base environment then it would work in jupyter notebook. otherwise you could try it to put in any specific environment and after activating it will work